# Javascript textarea word limit

Tags: javascript

I know that HTML has a `maxlength` attribute, but I want to limit the number of *words* typed not characters.

After 10 words the user should be able to move his cursor left & edit the text, but not add any more words.

So how can I stop the cursor?

Any suggestions?

Only javascript please.

Comment: @akonsu you can understand that? O_O

Comment: @kakonosze you mean do u want to focus out?

Comment: I want just stop currsor and i must use javascript :) What u mean focus out?

Comment: @karkonosze what do u mean by stopping cursor? you want to stop user from inputting more data?

Comment: yes, but user can back cursor! If u think about atribut disable or readonly this is not good for me.

Comment: @karkonosze check my answer, i think it might be closer to what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cover all possible user actions, but I was bored and maybe you'll learn something:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input_box"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
function check_words(e) {
    var BACKSPACE  = 8;
    var DELETE     = 46;
    var MAX_WORDS  = 10;
    var valid_keys = [BACKSPACE, DELETE];
    var words      = this.value.split(' ');

    if (words.length >= MAX_WORDS && valid_keys.indexOf(e.keyCode) == -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        words.length = MAX_WORDS;
        this.value = words.join(' ');
    }
}

var textarea = document.getElementById('input_box');
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', check_words);
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', check_words);
```

Try it on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/isikim/2/edit

- If there are 10 words in the `textarea` and the user presses a key, nothing will happen.
- If a user tries to copy and paste a big chunk of text, the contents of the `textarea` will immediately be stripped down to just 10 words.

Actually, I'm not sure it matters that this isn't perfect. Since JavaScript runs on the client, you just need something that will work for a normal user. Malicious users can always screw with your JavaScript; no way around that. As long as you're doing **real** sanitation on the server, there should be no problem.

Comment: u are realy fast! Now i must immplement this on my Fckeditor :)

Comment: what if i typed " this    is    a    test "? (edit to see extra spaces)

Comment: like i said, this solution is not perfect (easy to fix that with a regex though -- just trim all multiple spaces down to one space before splitting the string). like i also said, i don't actually recommend using this solution. it was just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

(The question isn't totally clear... I'm assuming it means "how do I prevent the user from typing more than ten words in a textarea?")

I think you'll struggle to achieve this.  What about Paste, for instance?

Here's an alternative suggestion, which might be appropriate for what you're doing: one way that modern UIs (eg. Twitter) deal with this is to put up a letter count or a word count, which turns red once you've gone past the limit.  You then get an error if you try to submit the form.  That's much easier to achieve than trying to prevent the user from typing more than ten words in the first place.

Comment: yes u have right! I think I saw something like that on difrent pages.

Comment: for the record, i definitely think this is the better approach. my answer is mostly just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 validation is made for tasks like these:

```
<input 
  pattern="([\w]+\s?){0,5}" 
  onkeypress="if(!this.validity.valid){this.value=this.value.slice(0,-1);return false;}"/>
```

if it's to be submitted, you can omit the onkeypress handler, as the form won't submit if something's invalid.

One can use poly-fills to support older browsers with this syntax.

Comment: what if i wanted to type `pokémon`?

Comment: @sgroves: we can use \S instead of \w if we define words as able to have non-wordy+non-space chars like "-" or "é" within.

Answer (score 0):

Like @sgroves this answer is just for fun :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
    // ignore backspaces
    if(e.keyCode == 8)
      return;

    var that = $(this);
    // we only need to check total words on spacebar (i.e the end of a word)
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
      setTimeout(function(){ // timeout so we get textarea value on keydown
        var string = that.val();
        // remove multiple spaces and trailing space
        string = string.replace(/ +(?= )| $/g,'');
        var words = string.split(' ');
        if(words.length == 10){
          that.val(words.join(' '));
        }
      }, 1);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oops just saw that its not a new line he wants but to only allow 10 words period. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar issue recently... here is my take

See demo below and on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/mQRrOM):

```js
'use strict';

let WordLimiter = function(el){

  el.constraints = {

    /**
     * Events to listen to
     */
    eventListeners: [
        'keyup',
        'input'
    ],

    events: {
      onWordLimiterCount: new CustomEvent('onWordLimiterCount',{
        detail: {
           value: 0,
           words: []
        }
      })
    },

    limit: null,
    validValue: '',

    /**
     * Checks if the
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    passed: function(){
      return this.wordCount() <= this.getLimit();
    },

    /**
     * Check if the element has a valid limit
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    hasLimit: function(){
      return false !== this.getLimit();
    },

    getLimit: function(){
      this.limit = parseInt( this.element.dataset.wordLimit );
      this.limit = isNaN( this.limit ) || this.limit <= 0 ? false : this.limit;
      return this.limit;
    },

    getWords: function(){
      this.words = this.element.value.split(' ');

      /**
       * Removes words that are just empty strings
       */
      this.words = this.words.filter(function (el) {
        return el !== null && el.trim() !== '';
      });
      return this.words;
    },

    /**
     * Gets the word count
     * Also triggers an event that you can hook into
     * @returns {number}
     */
    wordCount: function(){
      this.events.onWordLimiterCount.detail.words = this.getWords();
      this.events.onWordLimiterCount.detail.value = this.getWords().length;
      document.dispatchEvent(this.events.onWordLimiterCount );
      return this.events.onWordLimiterCount.detail.value;
    },

    /**
     * Checks constraints
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    verify: function(){
      console.clear();

      if( !this.constraints.passed() ){
        console.info( 'FAILED' );

        /**
         * Prevent any further input
         */
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        /**
         * Revert back to the last valid input
         * @type {string}
         */
        this.value = this.constraints.validValue;
        return false;
      }

      console.info( 'PASS' );
      this.constraints.validValue = this.value;
      return true;
    },

    /**
     * Scope purposes
     */
    element: el,
  };


  if( !el.constraints.hasLimit() ){
    console.groupCollapsed( 'TextArea does not have a valid limit' );
    console.info( el );
    console.groupEnd();
    return;
  }

  el.constraints.eventListeners.forEach(function(e){
    el.addEventListener(e, el.constraints.verify );
  });

};

/**
 * Looks for all textarea elements with the data-word-limit attribute
 */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  let textAreas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea[data-word-limit]");

  textAreas.forEach(function(i){
    new WordLimiter(i);
  });

}, true );

let CodePenDemo = {

  init: function(){
    document.addEventListener( 'onWordLimiterCount', function(e){
      document.getElementById('counter').value = e.detail.value;
    })
  },

  setWordLimit: function(){
    document.getElementById('textarea-limited').setAttribute( 'data-word-limit', event.srcElement.value );
  }
};

CodePenDemo.init();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container my-3">
        <h2>TextArea with Word Limit</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="word-limit">Word Limit</label>
            <input id="word-limit" type="number" min="1" class="form-control" value="50" onchange="CodePenDemo.setWordLimit();"/>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textarea-limited">TextArea</label>
            <textarea id="textarea-limited" class="form-control" data-word-limit="50" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="counter">Words Count</label>
            <input type="number" id="counter" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```